# Android : Decreasing size of the Button

Tags: android, android-button

I am using `Button` in one of the layouts. I want `Button` size to be as small as the text/label size.

I am using the following code.

```
<Button 
android:text="@string/cancle_button" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:background="@drawable/back_button" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

But I want `Button` height to be same as text/label height. Whenever I decrease or increase the text height, `Button` height remains the same. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: as you are passing an image in the background, so the button size would be dependent on the image size and then your text size. So if your text size is smaller than the image it won't decrease. But if the text size is larger than the image then it would grow to fit the text. This all happens because of the "wrap_content" property.

Comment: Thanks Arshad,but here i am using gradient drawable in .xml form in my drawable folder.

Comment: Even then the gradient also has a fixed size and shape. So works as the image itself.

Comment: The best thing to do is to adjust the gradient size as per the text size to get your work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative layout to achieve this. Check this sample code,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 187):

It's been almost a year since the question was asked. But I faced the problem now and got a solution. :)
May be it will help someone.

**You can achieve this by setting `android:minHeight="0dp"` for the Button widget.**

And I guess this behavior is because there is some default value (may be a 48dp) set for Button widgets by the framework considering a minimum touch area.

Answer (score 3):

Use can take the image view in this case or if your taking text view in this case so you can take the image with proper size so that it would not bluer through these measures you can set small size for image Best way is you can  take the image with that size you want to create its good way

Comment: In this requirement I am using gradient shape drawable in my drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by setting the button height to a specific value which is same as the height of your label.

```
<Button 
android:text="CANCEL" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:background="@drawable/back_button" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="20sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,is there any other way where button will adjust size automatically without hard coding it.I want Button size should change when text size changes

Comment: If you change the size of the text then as the height is set as wrap content it will automatically adjust that height

Comment: It is not adjusting button height is remaining same.

Comment: You simply make the height of button wrap content and change the size of the text it will adjust automatically. <Button 
android:text="CANCEL" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="125sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold" />

Answer (score 0):

### You can solve this by changing **layout_weight** of the button as by default it is set to "1"

Just set it to 0, and then you change the button_height by just changing the layout_height of the button.
Here is the code for a normal button-

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`android:minHeight="0dp"` -> To decrease button height as much as label size

`android:minWidth="0dp"` -> To decrease button width as much as label size

So;

```
<Button 
    android:text="@string/cancle_button"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp" 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/back_button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```